# How to get the memory size of a BlockingQueue in Java

Tags: java

I have a Java program that sent messages to an external Rest API. This API can handle a payload with a max size of 500KB only.

My messages are stored in a BlockingQueue. I was wondering if there is an easy way to check if the BlockingQueue memory size is below 500 KB and if I reach this size I just flush and call the API.

Is it the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: You can use LinkedBlockingQueue (bounded). That way you can control the implementation

Comment: https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer using this lib you can measure any object memory size.

Comment: Who says that the memory size of a block queue has any relation with the size of the serialized messages that you intend to send to the Rest API? Better approach: serialzie the messages that you can potentially combine before putting them in the blockqueue. Then the size of the individual messages is just the number of characters or bytes in the serialized form, which is easy to count.